# How Do I generate Line Graph in PowerBI for the following Data

Tags: date, graph, powerbi

The Data I have looked like the Image below:
[image]

I want to create a line Graph,

The x-axis will have the Months *(January to June)*, Y-Axis will have the *Tot_QtY*.
Considering that the date information is not in a single column but is spread out to multiple columns, How do I make a line chart.

**Output I am getting is shown below:**
[image]

**The Output I need would look like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your input data is not correct, you need to model it so you get one column with rows of data. Click Edit Queries, this opens query editor.

Click tab Transform, select your columns and click unpivot.

My expectation is that you still need to work a bit more on your data because how the system knows from a column: MayDATE. that you talk about May. The best base data you can have is a column date and a colum value with data.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will explore the Edit Queries option.